# Calculate height of a HTML-Table generated by HtmlTextWriter (C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, htmltextwriter

I generate a HTML-Page from C#. In the HTML-Page there are a lot of elements. All of them have a absolute position.

One of these elements is a table. This table represents a object that keeps a double[]. Every double value is a new cell in a new row.

I iterate over double[] and create my table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dbl.Length; i++)
{
  htmlTextWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Tr);
  htmlTextWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Td);
  htmlTextWriter.Write(dbl[i]);
  htmlTextWriter.RenderEndTag(); // td
  htmlTextWriter.RenderEndTag(); // tr
}
```

If the table has so much elements, that it cross an element that is below this table, I have to be responsive to this issue.

This means, I need to know how many pixels this table is long.

Of course I do know how many cells I generate and I also know BorderSize, Padding, Margin, etc.

But there are two problems. First although I know FontSize, FontFamily, FontWeight, I do not know how to include these information into a mathematical calculation.

Second I think in every browser the actual size is also different. I created a dummy table and recognized, that in one screen height I already have one cell difference between Opera and Firefox.

So I think in C# I am only able to approximate the actual height?!

The next idea I have is to include a JavaScript into my HTML. I've no experience with JavaScript, but my approach would be to find my tables and read out size. Then iterate over all elements and find all overlappings.

My questions are:

- Are my consideration true or do I miss some aspects?
- Are my approaches the right way (in C# I only will get an
  approximated result?!, JavaScript I do not know if it is really
  possible what I want to do)
- Are there other possibilities I do not see right now?

Hint: Other script languages than JavaSript are not applicable for my solution. JavaScript I only use if really necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think javascript is the answer, not c#.
http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: According to this description: Height does not include the Border, Padding and Margin? Is there a alternative which give me the complete size?

Comment: Hm, can't find such sentence? Anyway, I've just tried and border is included and height is returned same as in Firebug layout panel.

Comment: I assume that because of the image inside. Maybe this image is just wrong or I do missinterpret it

Comment: If you could give snippet that height is calculated wrong, it would be easier to tell what is going on. I think jQuery is one of the most polished javascript libraries available, so I'm kind of trusting it.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot calculate the height in C#. Please use javascript to do this.